# Trying to run a PowerShell script and there's a Browse For Folder error

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell and need to run a script that I downloaded from a company for troubleshooting purposes. This is done on a web server with no GUI, so I can only use PowerShell commands.

After I do the following commands in Administrator: Windows PowerShell,

```
PS D:\> ls

            Directory: D:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/1/2019   4:08 PM                Backups
d-----         7/9/2019  10:22 AM                certificates
d-----        6/20/2019   4:21 PM                inetpub
d-----        6/19/2019   2:57 PM                Installs
d-----        6/19/2019   2:56 PM                Program Files
d-----        6/19/2019   2:56 PM                Program Files (x86)
d-----        1/31/2020  11:50 AM                serverinfo
-a----        7/16/2019  11:43 AM              2 tmp

PS D:\> .\serverinfo\ServerInfo.ps1

Security warning
Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. Do you want to run D:\serverinfo\ServerInfo.ps1?
[D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "D"): R

Script has started
```

It then pops up with

[image]

As shown, there are no folders to be displayed, which I am confused about. Aren't Program Files, serverinfo, inetpub, etc all folders that should be there?

When I try to click "Make New Folder", nothing happens - I'm not able to make one.

Clicking the "OK" or "Cancel" button both say the same thing in PowerShell,

```
Select-Folder : Operation cancelled by user.
At D:\serverinfo\ServerInfo.ps1:46 char:9
+ $path = Select-Folder
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Select-Folder
```

What does this mean? What can I do to fix this and finally properly run my script?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here's the code for the ServerInfo.ps1 file. It's a long script, but the code regarding folders is near the beginning of it.
[ServerInfo.ps1](https://pastebin.com/g9hkVt0W)

Comment: Can you post the contents of the ServerInfo.ps1 file?

Comment: I assume the script want to access some resources that are not available in your environment. Probably you should not fight with the script but to get the information somehow else. If the script is short enough to be posted here, it could be a starting point.

Comment: @MarkKram I went ahead and edited the post with a link to the script. It was too long for me to paste it wihin the post, so I used pastebin. It should be just the beginning of the code that correlates to the problem.

Comment: @harper Now added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post your Powershell version and environment infos?

I tried running the ServerInfo.ps1 script on my local machine and it worked flawlessly.

[image: preview]

My guess is that it could be a version, environment or permission issue.

For references i'm running Windows 10 1809 outside of a domain, with Powershell version 5.1.17763.771.

**EDIT:** Also make sure to unblock the script if you fully trust it, since you don't have access to a GUI, you could do something like this :

`Get-ChildItem D:\Path\To\Script.ps1 | Unblock-File`

I would also advise to try and run the problematic code in it's own script also and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply (I'm an intern and haven't worked on this in a while). I managed to finally be able to select a folder, and it could finally run the script in PS ISE. It went through all of the commands from "Removing existing serverinfo.zip file if it exists on the disk" to "Getting the content of the Upgrade log if there is any". But then when it tries to execute the next command "Passwordstate Gateway Directory Properties" it shows an error saying "Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path 'C:Hosts\Gateway' because it does not exist". I'm not sure why it says that? How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm assuming the "C:Hosts\Gateway" missing the first "\" is a typo on your part in the comment? Otherwise make sure the path exists and is accessible by the script, making sure there is no permission issue or escape and invalid characters that could prevent the command from working correctly. Try running a Get-ChildItem on that Path outside of the script to make sure.